# Удалить элемент из массива по значению

Tags: golang

Привожу упрощенный код:

```
type Hello struct {}
...
var list []Hello
...
hello1 := Hello{}
hello2 := Hello{}
hello3 := Hello{}
list = append(list, hello1, hello2, hello3)
...
```

Затем понадобилось удалить из list элемент hello2. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранить слайс структур по значению - это плохо. Они туда копируются каждый раз.

И это не придирка, так у тебя будет "течь" память.

Представим что ты добавил 1000 элементов в []Hello, слайс ссылается на массив где хранятся эти 1000 элементов (а реально capacity может быть и больше необходимого и тогда там будут лежать `new(Hello)`), но потом ты решил удалить 500, и как бы ты не сдвигал "окошко" слайса в нижележащем массиве всегда будут храниться либо твои "удаленные" структуры, либо тебе придется их перезатирать элементами `new(Hello)` (тогда удаленные заберет сборщик мусора) и все равно это жрет память как для cap(list) элементов. Пока, конечно, ты снова не добавишь 500 элементов и тогда они реально перезатрутся и сборщик мусора сможет их забрать. И если у тебя "жирная" структура с большим количеством полей и/или вложенными структурами (по ссылке или копией), каналами и прочим то все это тоже будет висеть в памяти, пока не перезатрешь новыми элементами.

Правильный подход будет хранить слайс указателей, они хотя бы жрут память независимо от количества полей и их типа в структуре.

```
type Hello struct {}
...
var list []*Hello
...
hello1 := &Hello{}
hello2 := &Hello{}
hello3 := &Hello{}
list = append(list, hello1, hello2, hello3)
```

Тогда функция для удаления

```
func Remove(list []*Hello, item *Hello) []*Hello {
    for i, v := range list {
        if v == item {
            copy(list[i:], list[i+1:])
            list[len(list)-1] = nil // обнуляем "хвост"
            list = list[:len(list)-1]
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

Причем, сравнение v == item отработает правильно даже если это два разных указателя на одну и ту же структуру.

И удалять можно как

```
list = Remove(list, hello2)
```

Обрати внимание, что слайс нужно переприсвоить как и в случае с добавлением.

По поводу обнуления хвоста. Если ты просто уменьшишь длину слайса, то в нижелещащем массиве все равно останется ссылка на структуру, которая тебе уже не нужна, и сборщик мусора не сможет ее забрать.

Полезные приемы [Slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)

Answer (score 0):

append(slice[:index], slice[index+1:]...)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]